# PostgreSQL user with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app on heroku . For that I changed from sqlite3 to pg because heroku doesn't support sqlite3. I changed things in database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.pg

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.pg

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/my_database_production.pg
```

I also did add the gem and install it (gem install pg) . When I try to run bundler exec rake db:create it gives me the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "flo" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:909:in `initialize'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/flo/Ruby/sample_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am trying to write su - postgres in my terminal but from that command I get :

```
No passwd entry for user 'postgres'
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Either add some PostgreSQL user to your `config/database.yml` or edit `/etc/postgresql/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf` file and add your user appropriate permissions.

Comment: @blelump i only have postgres-xc it seems ...

Comment: really this is valid way for postgres database(`database: db/development.pg`)? i never see it later....

Comment: database: db/my_database_production.pg well i say where i want it created and when i run bundler exec rake db:create it should create it...

Comment: Where you find it `database: db/my_database_production.pg`? Can you post some link or any? Why you need write-scalable clustered `postgres-xc` instead normal `postgres`?

Comment: i don't but when i try to install the postgres thingy it gives me an error with the package . But since i can do install gem pg and it works there shouldn't be a problem with the database. The error is that there is no user flo, how could i possibly make that ...

Comment: What kind of error you have when you try install `postgres`?

Comment: sudo apt-get install postgresql-client i run this . And i get : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-client : Depends: postgresql-client-9.3 but it is not going to be installed . 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. I took it from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: you try install client, so postgresql server is already installed? `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`

Comment: i tried that also . same error : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66139/discussion-between--and-lucian-tarna).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the user 'flo' to your local postgres instance (I usually just add them as a super user so I don't have permissions issues). Run this in your terminal:

```
createuser -P -s -e flo
```

You will be prompted to set a password as well. Lets use 'flo' for now. You will then need to add this to your databases.yml file:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.pg
  username: flo
  password: flo
```

Do that and then try running `rake db:create` again. Check [this out for additional help](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-createuser.html).

Comment: createuser -P -s -e flo
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
7createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "flo" does not exist